# GetPreviewBitmapFile save preview bitmap with strange colors (SolidWorks)

Tags: c#, bitmap, solidworks, vsta

I'm developing C# VSTA macro for our manufacturing department.
I'm using `SldWorks.GetPreviewBitMapFile` to save a bitmap preview of the selected model and show it in the picturebox as shown below:

[image]

The code looks fine and execute fine except for the strange colors:

```
bool status = swApp.GetPreviewBitmapFile(filepath, configuration, "D:\\preview.bmp");
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "D:\\Preview.bmp";
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and what's the remedy?

Comment: Did you try to save image with GetPreviewBitmap?
var h = swApp.GetPreviewBitmap("Part11.SLDPRT", "Default");
Bitmap iconBitmap = Bitmap.FromHicon(h.handle);
iconBitmap.Save("Part11.bmp");

Comment: Cannot use var. I'm using C# 2.0

Comment: It is strange, GetPreviewBitmap works fine in VBA macro, but doesn't work in .net macros.

Comment: After digging a bit, it turns out the var keyword is only available in C# 3.0 and higher. I'm using VSTA 2005, so I can't get the handle/pointer using var. Perhaps, there's another way to get the pointer using GC (Garbage collector)? I will be very grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Do you use SolidWorks x64? In api help noted that GetPreviewBitmap is not supported in macros in SolidWorks x64. In this case convertging macros to addin might be solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of working code:

```
//to compare output
iSwApp.GetPreviewBitmapFile(@"c:\Path\Part1.SLDPRT", "Default", @"c:\Path\Part1_0.bmp");

object com = iSwApp.GetPreviewBitmap(@"c:\Path\Part1.SLDPRT", "Default");
stdole.StdPicture pic = com as stdole.StdPicture;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap((IntPtr)pic.Handle);
bmp.Save(@"c:\Path\Part1_1.bmp");
```

There are few notes about GetPreviewBitmap from SW API:

- Currently only in-process applications (that is, macros or add-ins) can use this method; out-of-process applications (that is, executables) will get an automation error because the IPictureDisp interface cannot be marshalled across process boundaries. This is a Microsoft behavior by design. See the Microsoft Knowledge Base for details.
- This method is not supported in macros or out-of-process applications in SolidWorks x64.

I was able to make it work in SolidWorks x64 only in .NET add-in and in VBA macros.
Let me know if you need add-in example.

Comment: Code's not working in .NET macro. The `GetPreviewBitmap` is returning a null. I'm running SW15 on a Win X64.

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in my reply "This method is not supported in macros or out-of-process applications in SolidWorks x64". I made it work in add-in. Did you consider to update your macros to SW add-in? I didn't find another way to get preview except SWDocumetManager, but it's different story and I'm not sure if you have serial key for it.

Comment: I've emailed the API support. They said it's a high priority bug and that they're working on it. They've suggested I use the ModelDoc2.SaveBMP instead. Thank you for your @Vladyslav. I'm going to tick your answer.

Answer (score 2):

An update for SW2016.
The GetPreviewBitmapFile function works for an out-of-process Csharp console program. However, the colors of the generated bitmap are very strange. It turns out the only valid solution is to use the SaveBmp function.